# How can I send data from react native to raspberry pi?

Tags: python, react-native, mqtt

I am currently working on a react native app and raspberry pi operating system. On my app I have a button that records sound and I have converted the sound to number values, I now want to send this data to raspberry pi so it can be recieved and sent as well as the temperature, pressure and humidity to thingspeak, how do I go about doing this.

I tried react-native-bluetooth but the raspberry pi system has no bluetooth and doesn't allow me to install bluez. The idea here is, I record using the react-native app, I record sound, the sound is converted to numbers, I want to send now these numbers to the raspberry pi

these are my codes so far:

React native:

```
const startRecording = async () => {
    (async () => {
      let { status } = await Audio.requestPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        console.log('Permission to access location was denied');
        return;
      }
      try {
        const recording = new Audio.Recording();

        await recording.prepareToRecordAsync(
          Audio.RecordingOptionsPresets.HIGH_QUALITY
        );
        recording._options?.isMeteringEnabled;
        recording.setOnRecordingStatusUpdate((status) => {
          const scaledValue = (Number(status?.metering) + 160) / 160;
        });
        await recording.startAsync();
        setRecording(recording);
        setIsRecording(true);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    })();
  };
```

Raspberry Pi python sript

```
t_transport = "websockets"
t_port = 80

# Create the topic string.
topic = "channels/" + channel_ID + "/publish"

while(True):
    # build the payload string.
    temperature = sense.get_temperature()
    humidity = sense.get_humidity()
    pressure = sense.get_pressure()
    
    payload = "field1=" + str(temperature) + "&field2=" + str(humidity) + "&field3=" + str(pressure)
    
    # attempt to publish this data to the topic.
    try:
        print("Data sent: Temperature: ", temperature ," Humidity: ", humidity, " Pressure: ", pressure)
        publish.single(topic, payload, hostname=mqtt_host, transport=t_transport, port=t_port, client_id=mqtt_client_ID, auth={'username':mqtt_username,'password':mqtt_password})
        time.sleep(15)        
    except(keyboardInterrupt):
        break
```

I want to recieve the data from the app and send it to thingspeak with this python script

Comment: If you can get your Pi to serve HTTP requests (ie running Flask or Node or whatever), you could do it all with axios/fetch (or websockets) over your local network. You could even use ngrok to connect remotely.

Comment: I thought about that, but let me try it out and see how it behaves, thank you

Comment: Why do you need the python? Why not send direct from the React code with MQTT?

Comment: Reason being, I want to also merge the data with the humidity, pressure and temperature so I can also insert this into a database, would've opted to send straight with mqtt but I want to do it as a unit

Comment: Hello . do you find a solution form this.